# Do the emission of electrons affect spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy

When we are heating an element to observe its spectrum does it lead to the thermal emission of electrons if yes then do these emissions affect the spectra that we observe if no then why the thermal emission and take place? Is there any best temperature to observe the spectrum?

Comment: In what specific way is this heating taking place? If the element is in a gaseous phase, is there also an increase in pressure?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking of [atomic spectra](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html), to measure  a spectrum one has to excite electrons from the atom, leaving an energy level unoccupied , and then the positive ion attracts an electron which releases the photon that makes up the spectral line to be recorded. This is for a helium gas:

[image: helspectr]

These spectra characterize the atom uniquely and do not change in within an inertial frame. In the example the electrons were excited out of the atom by high voltage.

If the sample is heated in order to excite the electrons to ionize the atom, it makes no difference to the atomic spectrum, but it  makes a difference to the [black body spectrum](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/wien.html) of the sample , which depends on temperature.

There also exist molecular spectra (not electron transitions) of radiation due to the interactions of the fringe fields of  molecules. Those collective spectra are affected by the temperature as seen for [example here](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2006/14/aa3256-05.pdf).

Comment: Nice answer. "and then the positive ion attracts an electron which releases the photon", can you please explain this a little bit, why (or how) does a recombination of an ion (with an electron) cause the release of a photon? This is not the same as when an electron that is already in the atom de-excites, releasing energy (this example is more understandable I think). But the case of recombination I think needs maybe more explanation?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei the electrons realeased by the heat induced scattering have practically zero energy with respect to the ion. They can be trapped at the n very large continuum level very easily, and radiate down from there.http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/imgmod/hyde3.gif

Comment: I think I understand, you are saying that the electron that is captured goes to a high energy level, and then de-excites and radiates because of that de-excitation? I might ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

If a gaseous sample of an element is heated and as a result of its higher temperature, emits radiation, then that *is* thermal radiation.

The form of the thermal radiation spectrum is dependent on temperature.

Broadly speaking, at relatively low temperatures there will be some excitation of ground state atoms into excited states. Or, if the gas is in molecular form then you would excite the molecules into higher rotational and vibrational states. There will then be transitions downward resulting in a spectrum of discrete lines at frequencies corresponding to the difference in energy levels.

As the temperature increases, higher energy levels in the atoms/molecules will increasingly be occupied and the spectral lines corresponding to downward transitions from these higher levels will increase in brightness.

If you were to look at the spectrum with very good frequency resolution you might be able to see the lines becoming broader as the temperature (and pressure) increases. This is due to a combination of [Doppler broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_broadening) and [pressure broadening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line#Pressure_broadening).

If the temperature increases further then it is possible for any molecules to dissociate and for some of the atoms to become ionised. The temperature at which this occurs will depend on the ionisation energy of the atoms and on the density of the gas. Free electrons can recombine with ions, or attach themselves to atoms to produce negative ions, resulting in a photo-recombination$^1$ continuum in the spectrum. This is largely what visible sunlight consists of - a continuum caused by the formation of H$^{-}$ ions at temperatures of $\sim 6000$ K.

If the temperature increases further, then more ions and electrons are created. The free electrons can take part in free-free interactions where the electrons are accelerated in the electric fields of the ions producing [bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) continuum radiation up to a frequency $f \sim k_BT/h$.

The continuum contribution to the spectrum will get stronger, relative to the lines, as the temperature increases. The line spectrum would also change once ionisation occurs, since the energy levels in the ions are different to those in atoms.

$^1$ Photo-recombination is the opposite process to [photo-ionisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoionization). An ion captures and electron (into a bound energy level) and a photon is emitted. Because the free electron starts with an energy that could have a continuum of values, then the emitted photon due to recombination can have a continuum of possible frequencies.

Comment: I am sorry I am a rookie can you please explain to me what is photo recombination continuum?

Comment: @PreetBhati see edit

Comment: Nice answer. Though I have a question, "If a gaseous sample of an element is heated and as a result of its higher temperature, emits radiation, then that is thermal radiation." and then you say "Broadly speaking, at relatively low temperatures there will be some excitation of ground state atoms into excited states." It sounds like you are saying that as the gas is heated, electronic transitions happen because of the kinetic energy that the gas gains? I thought when a gas is heated, the energy goes primarily into the kinetic (vibrational) energy of the molecules.

Comment: I think what you are saying is primarily for like when gas is heated by EM radiation? Not for the case for example when gas is heated by the collision of the molecules (with other molecules, in the environment for example).

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Thermal radiation is radiation that arises from a gas that can be characterised by an equilibrium temperature. If the gas is in molecular form then all you get is roational and vibrational tensitions. I guess relatively low temperatures for an astrophysicist is higher than that. I might modify to make clear. As for the second comment, it makes no difference how the gas is heated.